# Ошибка при cериализизации коллекции объектов в XML

Tags: c#, c#-8.0

Пытаюсь сериализировать коллекцию в XML:

```
public static void Serializeworker(List<Worker> fulWorkers, string path)
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Worker));
    FileStream f = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
    serializer.Serialize(f, fulWorkers);
    f.Close();
}

List<Worker> workers = new List<Worker>() { worker1, worker2, worker3, worker4, worker5, worker6, worker7, worker8, worker9, worker10, worker11, worker12 };
Serializeworker(workers, "_workers.xml");
```

При выполнении возникает исключение:

```
Необработанное исключение: System.InvalidOperationException: Ошибка при создании документа XML. ---> System.TypeAccessException: Методу "Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriterWorker.Write3_Worker(System.Object)" не удалось получить доступ к типу "дз_8_модуль.Program+Worker".
   в Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriterWorker.Write3_Worker(Object o)
   --- Конец трассировки внутреннего стека исключений ---
   в System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(XmlWriter xmlWriter, Object o, XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces, String encodingStyle, String id)
   в System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(Stream stream, Object o, XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces)
   в System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(Stream stream, Object o)
   в дз_8_модуль.Program.Serializeworker(List`1 fulWorkers, String path) в C:\Users\Василевский НА\Documents\дз 8 модуль\дз 8 модуль\Program.cs:строка 70
   в дз_8_модуль.Program.Main(String[] args) в C:\Users\Василевский НА\Documents\дз 8 модуль\дз 8 модуль\Program.cs:строка 133
```

Класс `Worker`:

```
public struct Worker 
{
    public string name { get; set;} 
    public string surname { get; set;} 
    public int age { get; set;} 
    public Department b { get; set;} 
    public int number { get; set;} 
    public int salary { get; set;} 
    public int project { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: как минимум стоит поменять `new XmlSerializer(typeof(Worker))` на `new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Worker>))`

Comment: Насколько я помню, должны быть ещё теги `[XmlRoot("")]` у Worker и `[XmlElement("")]` у его свойств

Comment: А так, вот дан ответ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2292480/xmlserializer-list-item-element-name

Comment: @Frehzy у меня и без тегов всё работает https://dotnetfiddle.net/d7YDdb

Comment: Точнее атрибутов